# Assembly error in Crystal ReportViewer in server machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Found following error.When Crystal Report Viewer is placed in asp.net page. :-

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Following is the Asp.net page html.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportItems.aspx.cs" Inherits="MvcNUnit.AspForms.ReportItems" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                        AutoDataBind="true" 
            DisplayToolbar="False" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with crystal-reports, it states that it can't find/load `log4net`

Comment: log4net.dll is place in bin folder in server machine.But works fine on local host

Comment: Confirm that the log4net dll is using the correct path and pointing to the bin folder in your solution. This is not a Crystal error.